# Android - allow installation of own developed apps beyond "unknown resources" only from your computer

Tags: android, custom-installation

When i want to put my changed app via usb on my mobile, I have to allow installation from unknown resources.

I can toggle this setting each time when I put a new version on my mobile, but doing so takes some effort and boring.

Is there a way to allow installation of own apps app's keeping the installation from unknown resources unset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy. Upon connecting your newly flashed / upgraded mobile, you will get a question whether you trust this new computer/phone. That's it - that's enough.